# Shared function to get configuration parameter for console, web app and Service Fabric microservice

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I want to have a shared function that returns the application setting of a parameter:

```
public static string GetAppSettings(string key)
{
  string sfAppName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Fabric_ApplicationName");
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sfAppName)) // we are NOT in SF 
     {
         return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
     }
     else
     {
         ConfigurationPackage configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
         return configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["appSettings"].Parameters[key].Value;
      }
}
```

So that this function gets the parameter from appSettings.config if the calling code is running in a standard web app, and from Local.1Node.xml if the calling code is running as a Service Fabric microservice.

When I put this function outside of the MicroServices "folder" (in the Shared project) I can't import

```
using System.Fabric;
```

Is there a way a way to do this? And is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, in your shared project, add a reference to the [Microsoft.ServiceFabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-fabric?view=azure-dotnet) [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric) package.

`Install-Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric`
or
`dotnet add package Microsoft.ServiceFabric`

Comment: Adding a dependency between standard webapps and  Microsoft.ServiceFabric Nuget package will have bad effects?